# Python метод replace и f-string

Tags: python, строки, файлы, replace, f-strings

Есть f-строка с текстом, который мне нужно изменить. Изменить не только значение переменной, но и сохранить изменения в файл, чтоб при перезапуске программы строка не возвращалась к своему изначальному значению.

Вот так всё работает правильно:

```
text = "Simple text."

def text_change(new_text):
    global text
    old = text
    new = new_text

    text = text.replace(old, new)  # меняю значение переменной

    with open("main.py", "r") as file:  # открываю файл
        old_data = file.read()

    new_data = old_data.replace(old, new)  # нахожу в нём нужную мне строку и изменяю её

    with open("main.py", "w") as file:  # сохраняю изменения в файле
        file.write(new_data)

    file.close()  # закрываю поток

text_change(new_text="New simple text.")  # запускаю функцию
```

Функция корректно работает, изменяется значение переменной, файл перезаписывается, при перезапуске программы изменения сохраняются.

Но если изменить переменную text на:

```
f_text = "f-string"
text = f"Simple text with using\n" \
       f"{f_text}"
```

Текст в переменной меняется, но изменения не записываются в файл. При перезапуске программы, переменная text возвращается к своему стандартному значению.

Как правильно адаптировать мою функцию под изменение f-строк?

Comment: Все настройки и другие параметры нужно хранить отдельно от кода. Тогда и не придётся придумывать всяческие извращения для их правки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `text_change` ищет и заменяет строку `old` в файле `main.py`, но когда вы используете f-строку, строка old не совпадает с текстом в файле, поскольку она может иметь разный формат. Чтобы адаптировать ф-ю для f-строк, вы можете задать строку old как конкретную f-строку, которую вы хотите изменить :

```
old = f"Simple text with using\n{f_text}"
```

Если вам нужно заменить множество f-строк в файле, стоит смотреть в сторону регулярных выражений.

```
import re

def text_change(new_text):
    global text
    old = f"Simple text with using\n{f_text}"
    new = new_text
    
    text = re.sub(old, new, text)

    with open("main.py", "r") as file:
        old_data = file.read()

    new_data = re.sub(old, new, old_data)

    with open("main.py", "w") as file:
        file.write(new_data)

    file.close()
    
text_change(new_text="New simple text.")
```

или так:

```
    import ast
    
    def text_change(new_text):
        global text
        old = f"Simple text with using\n{f_text}"
        new = new_text
        
        text = ast.literal_eval(f"f'{old}'").replace(f_text, new_text)
 with open("main.py", "r") as file:
        old_data = file.read()

    new_data = old_data.replace(old, text)

    with open("main.py", "w") as file:
        file.write(new_data)

    file.close()
    
text_change(new_text="New simple text.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во-первых, текст-то меняется, но только в переменной `text`. А в файл пишется переменная `new_data`, в которой текст не меняется. Потому что в ней ищется текст

```
Simple text with using
f-string
```

а такого текста в ней нет.

Опишите точно задачу, которую решаете, потому что это похоже на проблему XY.